# is Gap Limit only for consecutive address?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Suppose we generated 35 address, 1 to 5 are paid, 6 to 34 not paid/used and 35 paid.
Because of 20 gap limit we won't see 35 in our wallet, but what happen if we send some money to address 19 for example, will that fix the gap limit problem because even when are still having 28 not used address they are not in a row?

Answer (score 1):

The gap limit is the number of consecutive unused addresses after the highest used address. So if address 19 receives some Bitcoin, then, with a gap limit of 20, the next 20 addresses will become the lookahead. Since 35 will then be seen, the next 20 after address 35 become the lookahead.

Comment: OK, perfect, so a way to fix the gap limit is to pay for only the 20th gap address, not all the 20 unused addresses (this is what is doing Blockonomics I think: https://blog.blockonomics.co/bitcoin-what-is-this-gap-limit-4f098e52d7e1)